# array index out of bounds not fired

Tags: java

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] data) {
    for (int i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
        int current = data[i];
        int j = i-1;
        while (j >=0 && data[j] >= current) {
            data[j+1] = data[j];
            j--;
        }
        data[j+1] = current;
    }
}
```

the line  while (j >=0 && data[j] >= current)  should throw array index of bounds when data[-1] for the first time. I dont understand why it does not.  Can some one please help
Thank you
Ashok Pappu

Comment: And what about `j >=0`? AFAIK `-1 >= 0` is false.

Comment: @ppa The execution flow never gets to that line

Comment: At that point, `j==-1` and hence the condition `j>=0` is false. The while loop `while (j >=0 && data[j] >= current)` will immediately break on `j>=0` and hence there is no out of bounds exception.

Comment: Short answer: learn java.  java expressions are short circuiting.  if J>=0 is false the right side of && does not evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean expressions like these are never fully evaluated if the condition can be met earlier.

So...in your case since `j >= 0` is `false` and `false && ???` will always be `false` the second part does not need to get evaluated. This is why `data[-1]` will never be called.

You can use the same principle for `null` checks, e.g.

```
if (object != null && object.isSomething())
```

Answer (score 0):

If `while` clause contains more, than 1 expression, splitted by `&&`, they are executed one by one. This is done to increase performance.
I.e. at first in your code `j >= 0` will checks. If `j < 0`, it false. So, cycle will be interrupted regardless of the 2nd expression.